# Java Streams: Combining two collections into a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two Collections, a list of warehouse ids and a collection of widgets. Widgets exist in multiple warehouses in varying quantities:

```
List<Long> warehouseIds;
List<Widget> widgets;
```

Here's an example defeinition of classes:

```
public class Widget {
    public Collection<Stock> getStocks();
}

public class Stock {
    public Long getWarehouseId();
    public Integer getQuantity();
}
```

I want to use the Streams API to create a Map, where the warehouse ID is the key, and the value is a list of Widgets with the smallest quantity at a particular warehouse. Because multiple widgets could have the same quantity, we return a list.

For example, **Warehouse 111** has **5** qty of **Widget A**, **5** of **Widget B**, and **8** of **Widget C**.

**Warehouse 222** has **0** qty of **Widget A**, **5** of **Widget B**, and **5** of **Widget C**
The Map returned would have the following entries:

`111 => ['WidgetA', 'WidgetB']`

`222 => ['WidgetA']`

Starting the setup of the Map with keys seems pretty easy, but I don't know how to structure the downstream reduction:

```
warehouseIds.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Function::Identity,
    HashMap::new,
    ???...
```

I think the problem I'm having is reducing Widgets based on the stock warehouse Id, and not knowing how to return a Collector to create this list of Widgets. Here's how I would currently get the list of widgets with the smallest stock at a particular warehouse (represented by **someWarehouseId**):

```
widgets.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    (Widget w)->
        w.getStocks()
        //for a specific warehouse
        .stream().filter(stock->stock.getWarehouseId()==someWarehouseId)
        //Get the quantity of stocks for a widget
        .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Stock::getQuantity)),
    //Use a tree map so the keys are sorted
    TreeMap::new,
    //Get the first entry
    Collectors.toList())).firstEntry().getValue();
```

Separating this into two tasks using forEach on the warehouse list would make this job easy, but I am wondering if I can do this in a 'one-liner'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tacke this problem, we need to use a more proper approach than using a `TreeMap` to select the values having the smallest quantities.

Consider the following approach:

- We make a `Stream<Widget>` of our initial widgets. We will need to do some processing on the stocks of each widget, but we'll also need to keep the widget around. Let's `flatMap` that `Stream<Widget>` into a `Stream<Map.Entry<Stock, Widget>>`: that new Stream will be composed of each `Stock` that we have, with its corresponding `Widget`.
- We filter those elements to only keep the `Map.Entry<Stock, Widget>` where the stock has a `warehouseId` contained in the `warehouseIds` list.
- Now, we need to group that Stream according to the `warehouseId` of each `Stock`. So we use [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) where the classifier returns that `warehouseId`.
- The downstream collector collects elements that are classified to the same key. In this case, for the `Map.Entry<Stock, Widget>` elements that were classified to the same `warehouseId`, we need to keep only those where the stock has the lowest quantity. There are no built-in collectors for this, let's use [`MoreCollectors.minAll(comparator, downstream)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#minAll-java.util.Comparator-java.util.stream.Collector-) from the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library. If you prefer not to use the library, I've extracted its code into this answer and will use that.
- The comparator simply compares the quantity of each stock in the `Map.Entry<Stock, Widget>`. This makes sure that we'll keep elements with the lowest quantity for a fixed `warehouseId`. The downstream collector is used to reduce the collected elements. In this case, we only want to keep the widget, so we use [`Collectors.mapping(mapper, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) where the mapper returns the widget from the `Map.Entry<Stock, Widget>` and the downstream collectors collect into a list with [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

Sample code:

```
Map<Long, List<Widget>> map =
    widgets.stream()
           .flatMap(w -> w.getStocks().stream().map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, w)))
           .filter(e -> warehouseIds.contains(e.getKey().getWarehouseId()))
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
              e -> e.getKey().getWarehouseId(),
              minAll(
                Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getKey().getQuantity()), 
                Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList())
              )
           ));
```

with the following `minAll` collector:

```
public static <T, A, D> Collector<T, ?, D> minAll(Comparator<? super T> comparator, Collector<T, A, D> downstream) {
    return maxAll(comparator.reversed(), downstream);
}

public static <T, A, D> Collector<T, ?, D> maxAll(Comparator<? super T> comparator, Collector<? super T, A, D> downstream) {

    final class PairBox<U, V> {
        public U a;
        public V b;
        PairBox(U a, V b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    Supplier<A> downstreamSupplier = downstream.supplier();
    BiConsumer<A, ? super T> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
    BinaryOperator<A> downstreamCombiner = downstream.combiner();
    Supplier<PairBox<A, T>> supplier = () -> new PairBox<>(downstreamSupplier.get(), null);
    BiConsumer<PairBox<A, T>, T> accumulator = (acc, t) -> {
        if (acc.b == null) {
            downstreamAccumulator.accept(acc.a, t);
            acc.b = t;
        } else {
            int cmp = comparator.compare(t, acc.b);
            if (cmp > 0) {
                acc.a = downstreamSupplier.get();
                acc.b = t;
            }
            if (cmp >= 0)
                downstreamAccumulator.accept(acc.a, t);
        }
    };
    BinaryOperator<PairBox<A, T>> combiner = (acc1, acc2) -> {
        if (acc2.b == null) {
            return acc1;
        }
        if (acc1.b == null) {
            return acc2;
        }
        int cmp = comparator.compare(acc1.b, acc2.b);
        if (cmp > 0) {
            return acc1;
        }
        if (cmp < 0) {
            return acc2;
        }
        acc1.a = downstreamCombiner.apply(acc1.a, acc2.a);
        return acc1;
    };
    Function<PairBox<A, T>, D> finisher = acc -> downstream.finisher().apply(acc.a);
    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}
```